# Bash single quote in filename and ffmpeg escaping

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, escaping

I want to convert a list of flac files to mp3 using ffmpeg.
I have written the list of files to convert in a file.

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line
do
    ffmpeg -i "$line" -ab 320k "${line%.flac}.mp3"
done < flac_list
```

It works, however when a filename contains a single quote, it does not work.
And here begins my escaping nightmare.
I have found dozens of combinations without find how to make it work.

Could someone help ?

Comment: What doesn't work? The code looks fine, although a possibly unrelated issue is that `ffmpeg` may be reading from standard input as well, consuming contents of `flac_list` meant for the `read` command.

Comment: Provide an example of the contents of `flac_list` that causes the issue.

Comment: That's it ! It had forgottent that ffmpeg could read stdin. Adding the -nostdin switch fix the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @chepner, the -nostdin flag appended to ffmpeg solves the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I have found too that ffmpeg has surprising problems sometimes if it encounters certain characters in the filename. I stumbled over this problem when converting m4a to mp3 using a script. I didn't know that an innocent single-quote is one of them.

What you can do - aside of reporting a bug to ffmpeg - is to test, whether your filename contains an unwanted character, and either rename the file or create a symbolic link to the file, using a "good" name, and undo these changes when your conversion is done.

Comment: The single quote was never the problem.

Comment: I see, but how can a missing `-nostdin` affect only files containing a single quote? This puzzles me.

Comment: The OP *thought* the single quote was the issue, but never provided any evidence that was the case.